# RuntimeException: "Stub!" without any other information

Tags: java, android, bluetooth

I'm trying to use [this library](https://github.com/NewtronLabs/EasyBluetooth?utm_source=android-arsenal.com&utm_medium=referral&utm_campaign=6178). I have implemented all callbacks and tried to start a server:

```
public class MasterActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_master);

        createBluetoothServer();
    }

    void createBluetoothServer(){
        IBluetoothServer btServer = new BluetoothServer.Builder(this.getApplicationContext(),
                "EasyBtService", ParcelUuid.fromString(uuid))
                .build();

        if (btServer == null){
            Log.e(this.getClass().getCanonicalName(), "Failed to create server!");
        } else {
            // Block until a client connects.
            IBluetoothClient btClient = btServer.accept();
            // Set a data callback to receive data from the remote device.
            btClient.setDataCallback(new DataReceivedCallbackMaster());
            // Set a connection callback to be notified of connection changes.
            btClient.setConnectionCallback(new ConnectionCallbackMaster());
            // Set a data send callback to be notified when data is sent of fails to send.
            btClient.setDataSentCallback(new DataSentCallbackMaster());
            btClient.sendData("ServerGreeting", "Hello Client".getBytes());
            //We don't want to accept any other clients.
            btServer.disconnect();
        }
    }
}
```

In the line:

```
IBluetoothServer btServer = new BluetoothServer.Builder(this.getApplicationContext(),
                "EasyBtService", ParcelUuid.fromString(uuid))
                .build();
```

I'm getting following exception:

```
Process: XXX, PID: 28033
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{XXX/XXX.Activities.MasterActivity}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Stub!
```

Without any usefull feedback. What that stub is supposed to mean? Has anyone already met with something like this and was able to solve it?

**EDIT: I'm adding my gradle files.** 
Project build.gradle:

```
buildscript {

    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven { url "http://code.newtronlabs.com:8081/artifactory/libs-release-local" }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'
        classpath "com.newtronlabs.android:plugin:2.0.0.alpha"
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven { url "http://code.newtronlabs.com:8081/artifactory/libs-release-local" }
    }
}

subprojects {
    apply plugin: 'com.newtronlabs.android'
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

And app build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "XXX"
        minSdkVersion 22
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.newtronlabs.easybluetooth:easybluetooth:2.0.0'
}
```

Comment: BLUETOOTH, BLUETOOTH_ADMIN and ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION.

Comment: Hi @serwus, thanks for reaching out! Could you post your gradle file so that we can help you out?

Comment: Wow, thank You for fast reply! I will edit my post in a moment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case you want to use `provided` for the library so that everything works smoothly. You want to make the change in the `gradle` file.

```
provided 'com.newtronlabs.easybluetooth:easybluetooth:2.0.0'
```

Comment: Now it works like a charm. I had problems with build.gradle file, at first I thought the problem was with the loading order, but then it complied and gived mentioned exception, so I was out of ideas. Thank You!

Comment: @serwus Glad to hear! You are welcomed. Here to help :)